# How to Create a Relationship between 3 binary vectors

Tags: vectors, binary-operations

I have two process that l will perform.

In the first process l have the following binary vectors that l would want to create relationship between them : A, B, C and the resulting F

Formulating a relationship between the three:

A ⊕ B = X1

X1 ⊕ C = X2

X2 ⊕ A = F

When first process is done, **B and F will be known** in the Second process. So we would want to find **C and A**

F = X2 ⊕ A

= X1 ⊕ C ⊕ A

= A ⊕ B ⊕ C ⊕ A

= B ⊕ C ⊕ 0

Therefore   **C = F ⊕ B**

l cannot find **A**. Any suggestions on how l can solve this and/or how to create the relationships.
where ⊕ is the exclusive or operator

Answer (score 1):

To recap, you have
$$\begin{aligned}
A \oplus B &= X_1 \\
X_1 \oplus C &= X_2 \\
X_2 \oplus F &= A \end{aligned} \label{NA1}\tag{1}$$
and you have determined that since
$$A \oplus B \oplus C \oplus F = A \label{NA2}\tag{2}$$
then
$$C = F \oplus B \label{NA3}\tag{3}$$

Thing is, modifying the value of $A$ only affects $X_1$ and $X_2$, which are free variables. For example, consider the case where we simply set $A = 0$, but keep $B$, $C$, and $F$ unchanged:
$$\begin{aligned}
0 \oplus B &= X_1^\prime \\
X_1^\prime \oplus C &= X_2^\prime \\
X_2^\prime \oplus F &= 0 \end{aligned}$$
Obviously, $X_1^\prime = B$, and $X_2^\prime = B \oplus C$, which leads to
$$B \oplus C \oplus F = 0$$
which is just $\eqref{NA3}$ reordered,
$$C = F \oplus B$$
In other words, if $C = F \oplus B$, unless you restrict $X_1$ or $X_2$ somehow, any $A$ including $A = 0$ will fulfill $A \oplus B \oplus C \oplus F = A$.